# Add pass parameters to my quiz so

Tags: javascript

Using this code I want to be able to have to separate questionnaires using the same code, just different correct answers.

As you can see I've just tried adding another answer onto the code array for a different quiz but it does not recognize the answer (Test). What is the best way of doing this? Someone told me you can use pass parameters to add different arrays or something?

Here is my whole code:

```
// Insert number of questions
var numQues = 4;

// Insert number of choices in each question
var numChoi = 3;

// Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
var answers = new Array(4);


// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = "Apple", "Test" ;
answers[1] = "Dynamic HTML";
answers[2] = "Netscape";
answers[3] = "Common Gateway Interface";

// Do not change anything below here ...
function getScore(form) {
var score = 0;
var currElt;
var currSelection;
for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
currElt = i*numChoi;
for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
  currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
  if (currSelection.checked) {
    if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
      score++;
      break;
    }
  }
 }
}
score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
form.percentage.value = score + "%";
var correctAnswers = "";
for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
}
form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;
} 
//  End -->
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because:

```
answers[0] = "Apple", "Test" ;
                          ^ just a string literal
```

`answers[0]` only has `Apple` as its value.

You should instead do:

`answers[0] = "Test";` I suppose.

Comment: And how do I fix this?

Comment: No this will still not work. I need this to work for 2 different questionaires. Using either answer Apple for questionnaire 1 or Test for questionnaire 2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for, there are a couple ways you could do this. One way is  to store an answer array for each quiz you have, and enumerate each quiz in an encapsulating array:

```
var quizKey = [
    ["Apple", "Dynamic HTML", "Netscape", "Common Gateway Interface"]
    ["Quiz2Answer1", "Quiz2Answer2", "Quiz2Answer3", "Quiz2Answer4"]
    ["Quiz3Answer1", "Quiz3Answer2", "Quiz3Answer3", "Quiz3Answer4"]
];
```

Now the array of answers for your first quiz would be in `quizKey[0]`, your second quiz's array of answers would be in `quizKey[1]`, and your third quiz's array of answers would be in `quizKey[2]`. You can easily add more answers dynamically:

```
var newSetOfAnswers = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "gaz"];
quizKey.push(newSetOfAnswers);
```

Just be sure to keep up with the enumeration.

In my opinion, a better way would be to name the quizzes so you don't have as much trouble trying to keep track of the number of the quiz, and you could store your keys in a map:

```
var quizKey = {
    "quiz" : ["Apple", "Dynamic HTML", "Netscape", "Common Gateway Interface"]
    "text" : ["Quiz2Answer1", "Quiz2Answer2", "Quiz2Answer3", "Quiz2Answer4"]
    "exam" : ["Quiz3Answer1", "Quiz3Answer2", "Quiz3Answer3", "Quiz3Answer4"]
};
```

Adding new sets of answers dynamically is just as easily, plus you get the opportunity to name it:

```
var newSetOfAnswers = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "gaz"];
quizKey["excellentTest"] = newSetOfAnswers;
```

Comment: You have helped me. But I am not a coder. Please could you correct all of my code so that it will work. If i just add what you have done this will not work as it is not linked to my other code at the bottom for calculating the score.

Comment: @user3560464 No. First, I can't. You didn't post your relevant HTML. Second, because nobody on StackOverflow will just write code for you, even if you offer to pay. We're here to help, but you have to be willing to put in some effort yourself.